# How to make sequential data into a group

Tags: perl

I am a newbie to Perl. Appreciate anybody can give me some suggestions and help here.

I have a file:

---

```
A1a01   A1a03  
A1a03   A1a0b  
A1a0b   A1a2a  
A1a2a   A1a02  
A1app   A1a06  
Ala06   A1a07  
A1b0v   A1b0c  
Alb0c   Alb55  
A1b55   A1b04  
..      ..  
..      ..  
.  
.  
.
```

I want to extract and print the sequential data into different groups. As you can see from the example given, the groups are from A1a01 to A1a02, A1app to A1a07, and A1b0v to A1b04. Each group is in sequential manner.

So far I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work to get what I need. I only manage to print those matched names after comparison of column1 and column2. I do not have idea how to extract the non-match names. (not sequential in order after compare column1 2nd name with column2 1st name of 2 rows data.) And I need to print each group first and last names.

```
use strict;  
use warnings;  

my $i;  
my $j;  
my @column1;  
my @column2;  
my @array1;  
my $lastname;  


@column1=`awk '{print \$1}' saved4`;  
@column2=`awk '{print \$2}' saved4`;  

    for ($i=0;$i<=$#column1;$i++){  
        for ($j=0;$j<=$#column2;$j++){  
                if ($column1[$i]=~ /$column2[$j]/){  

                   push (@array1,$column2[$j]);   
                           }  

        else {  
            $lastname = $column2[$j];  
            }  

            }  
}  

print "$column1[0] @array1 $lastname\n";
```

The expected result is like:

```
group1:  
A1a01   A1a03  
A1a03   A1a0b  
A1a0b   A1a2a  
A1a2a   A1a02  

group2:  
A1app   A1a06  
Ala06   A1a07  

group3:  
A1b0v   A1b0c  
Alb0c   Alb55  
A1b55   A1b04
```

Comment: Did you intentionally mix `1` (the number one) and `l` (lower case L) in your sample input/output or is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'print "group".++$i.":" if $a ne $F[0]; print; $a = $F[1];' group.txt
```

**Output:**

```
group1:
A1a01   A1a03
A1a03   A1a0b
A1a0b   A1a2a
A1a2a   A1a02
group2:
A1app   A1a06
A1a06   A1a07
group3:
A1b0v   A1b0c
A1b0c   A1b55
A1b55   A1b04
```

**Explanation:**

- `-l` handle newlines in input/output
- `-a` autosplit input on whitespace, strip excess whitespace
- `-n` read stdin or input from file
- `@F` the array autosplit elements are stored in

Basically this code loops for each line in the file (or stdin), if the first value on the line is not equal to the second value of the previous line, a new group-header is printed, and the counter is incremented by one.

If you have warnings on, you will get two warnings with this code, but since they are harmless here (uninitialized warning for first check on `$a` and typo-warning on `$i`) I opted not to turn warnings on.

The full code for this one-liner is:

```
$/ = "\n";
$\ = "\n";
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    our(@F) = split(' ', $_, 0);
    print 'group' . ++$i . ':' if $a ne $F[0];
    print $_;
    $a = $F[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my %groups = (A1a01 => 1, A1app => 2, A1b0v => 3);

open my $FILE, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Could not read file $ARGV[0]: $!";

flock $FILE, 2;

while ( <$FILE> ) {
    chomp;

    my @cols = split /\s/;

    print "\nGroup #$groups{ $cols[0] }:\n" if $groups{ $cols[0] };

    print join (' ', @cols), "\n";
}

close $FILE;
```

Comment: Splitting on a single whitespace is probably not a very good idea, use default split instead. Also, this makes the groups hard coded, not a very useful solution, as it requires you to first browse the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my (@arr1,@arr2);
open my $fh, '<', 'file' or die $!;
while(<$fh>){
        my ($x,$y)= split;
        push @arr1, $x;
        push @arr2, $y;
}
close $fh;

my $cnt=1;
print "Group $cnt \n";
my $i=0;
while (1) {
        if ($arr1[$i+1] eq $arr2[$i]){
                print "$arr1[$i]  $arr2[$i] \n";
        }else{
                print "$arr1[$i]  $arr2[$i] \n";
                print "Group ", ++$cnt , "\n";
        }
        $i++;
        if ($i+1==@arr1){
                print "$arr1[$i]  $arr2[$i] \n";
                last;
        }
}
```

On running this:

```
Group 1
A1a01  A1a03
A1a03  A1a0b
A1a0b  A1a2a
A1a2a  A1a02
Group 2
A1app  A1a06
A1a06  A1a07
Group 3
A1b0v  A1b0c
A1b0c  A1b55
A1b55  A1b04
```

Note:  Your file is not proper, at some places, it is given as 'l',instead of '1'.

Comment: Thanks @Guru. This is just matched to what I need =)

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;  
use warnings;  

my $i;  
my $j;  
my @column1;  
my @column2;  
my @array1;  
my $lastname;  

@column1=`awk '{print \$1}' saved4`;  
@column2=`awk '{print \$2}' saved4`;  

chomp @column1;
chomp @column2;

my @allGroups;
my $group = [ "- " . $column1[0] . "    " . $column2[0]];

for ($i = 0; $i <= $#column2; $i++){

    if ($i < $#column1-1) {

      if ($column2[$i]=~ /$column1[$i+1]/) {  

          push (@$group, "- " . $column1[$i+1] . "    " . $column2[$i+1]);

      } else {
          push (@allGroups, $group);
          $group = [ " - " . $column1[$i+1] . "    " . $column2[$i+1]];
      }  
    }  
}
foreach my $arr (@allGroups) {
   print "\n\nNEW GROUP\n";
   print @$arr;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
NEW GROUP
A1a01    A1a03 A1a03    A1a0b A1a0b    A1a2a A1a2a    A1a02

NEW GROUP
A1app    A1a06 A1a06    A1a07

NEW GROUP
A1b0v    A1b0c A1b0c    Alb55
```

Comment: I tried your code. It is perfectly working fine. Thanks a lot =)